# WebSocketpp handshake issue with TLS

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, websocket++

I have been learning with WebSocket++ and built some of the server examples (Windows 10 Visual Studio 2019). The non-TLS examples work without issues, however, the TLS-enabled examples (`echo_server_both.cpp` and `echo_server_tls.cpp`) can't do the handshake. I am very new to web development in general so I know I must be doing something wrong with regards to the certificate and keys.

I am testing the servers with WebSocket King client, an extension of Google Chrome that connects correctly to other websocket servers like `wss://echo.websocket.org` and to my own localhost when I don't use TLS.

The `echo_server_both` example comes with a `server.pem` file, and the `echo_server_tls` example comes with `server.pem` and `dh.pem`. I have used the same files that come with the samples, and I have also tried generating and registering my own .pem files using openSSL. In both cases I get this when the client tries to connect:

```
[2021-06-29 20:51:21] [error] handle_transport_init received error: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
[2021-06-29 20:51:21] [fail] WebSocket Connection [::1]:63346 - "" - 0 asio.ssl:336151574 sslv3 alert certificate unknown
[2021-06-29 20:51:21] [info] asio async_shutdown error: asio.ssl:336462231 (shutdown while in init)
```

I discovered these errors after I edited `handle_init()` in `tls.hpp`, following a suggestion in another site, to look like this:

```
void handle_init(init_handler callback,lib::asio::error_code const & ec) {
    if (ec) {
        //m_ec = socket::make_error_code(socket::error::tls_handshake_failed);
        m_ec = ec;
    } else {
        m_ec = lib::error_code();
    }

    callback(m_ec);
}
```

This change let the actual openSSL error to show in the console, otherwise it would show a generic "handshake failed" error.

I know I'm not doing what I should with the certificates, but I have no idea where else to look or what to do next. Can anyone here help please? Should I use the .pem files that come with the examples, or should I generate my own? in case I should generate my own, what would be the openSSL command to do that correctly and how do I tell my PC to recognize these as valid so that the server works?

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket++ will not accept a self-signed certificate (the ones you can create directly in your own PC using OpenSSL or the Windows utilities). There is no way around it.

You must have a valid, authority-validated and endorsed certificate. You can get such a certificate  for free (valid only for 90 days) from https://zerossl.com. The site has detailed instructions on how to request, obtain and install a certificate.

After getting a valid certificate and installing it on my server, everything worked as it should.

Comment: This isn't true. Letsencrypt certificates work perfectly fine with websocket++. There is no need to spend any money with zerossl.com.

Comment: Hey samster, thanks for the clarification. For the record, I didn't write my answer trying to endorse or publicize zerossl in any way. As I said in my main post, I am fairly new to web development, and I just searched for a company/site that would emit certificates, and the first one I found that offered me a free option was zerossl. Thanks to your message I now discovered letsencrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/), I will try these. In any case, what I said was that websocket++ does not accept a certificate created by oneself in any PC. I think that still holds true.